# login Button redirecting to mainpage instead of user page in android Studio app with firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, authentication

[image: Firebase Real time Database]

```
    public class loginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView signup;
    TextInputLayout phone,pass;
    Button btn_login;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        signup = findViewById(R.id.txt_signup);
        phone = findViewById(R.id.phone);
        pass = findViewById(R.id.pass);
        btn_login = findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                loginUser(view);
            }
        });

    }

    private boolean validatePhone(){
        String p = phone.getEditText().getText().toString();
        if(p.isEmpty()){
            phone.setError("field is empty!");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            phone.setError(null);
            phone.setErrorEnabled(false);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private boolean validatePass(){
        String p = pass.getEditText().getText().toString();
        if(p.isEmpty()){
            pass.setError("field is empty!");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            pass.setError(null);
            pass.setErrorEnabled(false);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void loginUser(View v){
        if(!validatePhone() | !validatePass()){
            return;
        }
        else {
            isUser();
        }
    }

    private void isUser(){
        final String appPhone = Objects.requireNonNull(phone.getEditText()).getText().toString().trim();
        final String appPass = Objects.requireNonNull(pass.getEditText()).getText().toString().trim();

        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
        Query checkUser = databaseReference.orderByChild("phone").equalTo(appPhone);
        checkUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    phone.setError(null);
                    phone.setErrorEnabled(false);

                    String fbasePass = dataSnapshot.child("pass").getValue(String.class);
                    assert fbasePass != null;
                    if(fbasePass.equals(appPass)){

                        phone.setError(null);
                        phone.setErrorEnabled(false);

                       // String uPhone = dataSnapshot.child(appPhone).child("phone").getValue(String.class);
                        String uPhone = dataSnapshot.child("phone").getValue(String.class);
                        String uAadhar = dataSnapshot.child("aadhar").getValue(String.class);
                        String ucity = dataSnapshot.child("city").getValue(String.class);
                        String ufname = dataSnapshot.child("fname").getValue(String.class);
                        String uemail = dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),usrHome.class);
                        intent.putExtra("phone",uPhone);
                        intent.putExtra("aadhar",uAadhar);
                        intent.putExtra("city",ucity);
                        intent.putExtra("fname",ufname);
                        intent.putExtra("email",uemail);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else {
                        pass.setError("Wrong password");
                        pass.requestFocus();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    phone.setError("Please Create Account First");
                    phone.requestFocus();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

when i click login button it is pause for sometime and automatically redirecting to main page of my application. 
i was using data from firebase realtime database in login activity.
please help me about this.. i wasted my 2 days to solve this problem but nothing is working.

in case if you have another code that can fulfill this requirement than please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are starting the LoginActivity before the Firebase actually logout the user. Try to add a `FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener` and just start the LoginActivity when the listener is trigged. See this post: [Firebase signout is not leading to the correct activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61664357/firebase-signout-is-not-leading-to-the-correct-activity/61666749#61666749)

Comment: can you please explain in detail? because i am new in android development.

Comment: It seems that you don't log out correctly. You are let log in and automatically goes to next activity. Be sure that you are logged out. Firebase uses internet, so it may make delay in code. @NilayPatel

Comment: i had not written any method for log out.i simply set intent which opens the next user profile page.

Comment: What do you have in usrHome? @NilayPatel

Comment: Check if if(fbasePass.equals(appPass)) runs or not, you can use logcat @NilayPatel

Comment: thank you very much for your support but it is issue with userHome page. now i created new activity and used it instead of userHome. and it works correctly.

Comment: If it is empty, what is the issue? @NilayPatel

Comment: i don't know but now new activity is working amazingly !